# Files listed in .gitignore are removed with git rm command

Tags: git

I have setup a `.gitignore` file with just one file in it:

```
 cat .gitignore
 README.md
```

The `.gitignore` file has these permissions:

```
ls -l README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 tdun0002 1049089 113 Mar 21 18:54 README.md
```

I'm not sure what the problem is but when I do a `git rm --force *` everything is removed including the `README.md` file listed in the `.gitignore` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your `.gitignore` in the same place as `README.md`? Was the file tracked *before* being added to `.gitignore`?

Comment: The `.gitignore` file is in the same directory as the `README.md` file. But I did not commit the `.gitignore` file to the repo. It is untracked. Do I need to commit it to the repo for this to work? The `README.md` file was tracked before I added the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Is there an assumption that an untracked ignored file will be ignored by `git rm`? Where does that assumption come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file is a way of specifying which untracked files will remain untracked even if you try to add them (and it's generally a good idea that any changes to it should be fully committed before attempting operations that use those changes). It is not a way to tell general `git` commands to not do stuff with a file.

In particular, if a file is already in the repo when you add it to the `.gitignore`, this will have no effect on it.

Since your `README.md` was already *in* the repo when you added it to `.gitignore`, it continued to be a tracked file.

---

Though that might not solve your *actual* issue: I'm having a hard time figuring out what your intent is, since this appears to be an XY problem - you're asking why the thing you tried didn't work, when we don't actually know what you were trying to do. The two possibilities that come to mind are discussed below:

1. If your intent is to *not* have `README.md` in the repo, just `git rm` it, then commit/push/etc.
2. If you *do* want it in the repo, it shouldn't *be* listed in the `.gitignore` file.
3. If you want to get rid of everything except a few files (and they're clean, in the sense that there are no uncommitted changes), you might find it easier to delete the lot then just check out the ones you want to keep. Something like `git rm . ; git checkout HEAD -- README.md`.
4. If you only want to remove specific files, you can use wildcards to limit them. For example, `git rm --dry-run [0-9a-zA-QS-Z]*` will not touch any files starting with `R`. You'll notice I've used `--dry-run` here since you'll probably want to check this option before allowing it to *actually* delete. Once you're happy it will do the right thing, just run it again *without* that option.

If it's something else you're trying to achieve, it'd be handy if you could expand on that.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to remove all of the files in that directory except for the `README.md` file in order to clean it up and replace that git directory with a different set of files and a different directory structure.  When I gave the `git rm *` command I was hoping it would leave the `README.md` file listed in the `.gitignore` file intact. I wanted `README.md` in the repo. Is there a way to exclude that file on the git command line?

Comment: @bluethundr, added a couple more options which may help you out, based on that previous comment.